# Constructing a function for getting combinatorics unique id

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following scenario:

Given 3 distance sensors that outputs integers (distance measured to an obstacle) in range $[1,r]$ where $r$ is the sensor range. the total number of possibilities is $r^3$. Given an array of size $r^3$, how to get a unique index for each one of the possible states.

For example: assume that the 3 sensors have a range from $[1,3]$. The I want to construct a function $f(s_1,s_2,s_3)$ such that $f(1,1,1)=0, f(1,1,2)=1, f(1,1,3)=2, f(1,2,1)=4,...etc$

Comment: $f(s_1,s_2,s_3)=(s_3-1)+r\times (s_2-1)+r^2\times (s_1-1)$.

Comment: Can you give a more generalized form for any number of sensors $s_n$?

Comment: My function is simply converting a three digit sequence into the number it represents base $r$. The same idea works for any length of sequence.